# Visual Basic RegularExpression Digits only

Tags: regex, vb.net

I should preface this by stating that Visual Basic is not my native language, but I am maintaining a legacy program until which time it can be ported to a different language.

We have a Textbox that is used to enter a quantity.  This quantity should be whole numbers only, and this was not being validated.  A decimal sneaked into the database and I've been asked to add validation of input.  I have tried a Regular Expression.

```
Function validate_qty(qty As String)
    Dim objRegExp As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^\d+$")
    Dim match As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = objRegExp.Match(qty)
    If match.Success Then
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

This is working as far as decimal points is concerned: `.1` and `1.0` return false; however, alphanumeric strings such as `a1212` or `433498e` return `True`

Any insight?  It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: whole numbers are `{0,1,2,3....}`..do you want numbers with decimal points to be validated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than shortening the function, I can't see a problem with your RegEx...

```
Private Function validate_qty(Byval qty As String) As Boolean
   Dim objRegExp As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^\d+$")
   Return objRegExp.Match(qty).Success
End Function
```

Another option would be to use the static `Integer.TryParse`...

```
Private Function validate_qty(Byval qty As String) As Boolean
   Return Integer.TryParse(qty, Nothing)
End Function
```

Comment: Yeah, the regex was fine, I was passing a copy of the quantity that had been parsed to a double into my function, while a non-parsed copy was being written to the database!  Nothing like taking over a project from a SystemAdmin who thinks he is a programmer.  And I like your shortened version, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need regex yet ..

```
Function validate_qty(qty As String) As Boolean
    if qty.Contains(".") then Return False
    Return IsNumeric(qty)
End Function
```

Comment: I need whole numbers only (integers) I thought IsNumeric woud return true for decimals, or did i misread that?

Comment: IsNumeric is so useless cause when it contains 8 numeric digits + 1 alpha numeric, it still keeps returning "true" like there is no alpha numeric but there is an alpha numeric there..

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function which returns a "cleaned" string (i.e. one that has any non-digits removed)

```
Public Function KeepNumbers(input As String) As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    For Each c As Char In input
        If [Char].IsDigit(c) Then
            sb.Append(c)
        End If
    Next
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: If `Boolean` is the preferred return type, then you could always check the length of the `sb.ToString()` and see if it is greater than zero. If so then you have a valid integer (`True`); otherwise not (`False`). This would of course require changing the function syntax to `Public Function KeepNumbers(input As String) As Boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

I also do not see where your error might be on your regex

but try.

```
btnSave/formload()
dim num as new regex("^\d+$")

if num.Ismatch(yourtextbox1.text) then    
    yourtextbox1.text="num" 

else 
    yourtextbox.text="invalid num"
    exit sub

end if
```

after this you accept if its correct or terminate by "exit sub " if its incorrect.